# Look for an elegant way to declare an array of struct with strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, coding-style

I'm trying do do something like what I've done in C++ with QT, in C.
This is a part of the C++ code:

```
typedef struct {
    int     order;
    int     type;
    QString cmd;
    QString res[2];
    double  timeout;
    int     exitAfterNChar;
}atCmdList_t;
atCmdList_t atCmdList[] = {
    {0,0, "ATI", {"", ""}, 1, -1},
    {0,0, "AT+GSN", {"", ""}, 1, -1},
    {0,0, "AT+COPS?", {"+COPS: 0,0,\"vodafone IT\",2", ""}, 1, -1}
};
```

I'm trying to make something similar in C.
I know that i can do sometring like this:

```
const char s_00[]  = {""};
const char s_01[]  = {"ATI"};
const char s_02[]  = {"AT+GSN"};
const char s_03[]  = {"AT+COPS?"};

typedef struct {
    int     order;
    int     type;
    const char *  cmd;
    const char *  res[2];
    double  timeout;
    int     exitAfterNChar;
} atCmdList_t;
atCmdList_t atCmdList[] = {
    {0,0, s_01, {s_00, s_00}, 1, -1},
    {0,0, s_02, {s_00, s_00}, 1, -1},
    ....
};
```

But this is not elegant and clear as the C++ way.
My "mission" is to make or find a precompiler macro that make the code as much readable as possible.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your current C code is wrong because, as it is, `&s_00` is not a pointer-to-const-char (`const char*`) but a pointer-to-pointer-to-const-char (`const char**`), because `s_00` is of type `const char[]`. Same for the others. So that must be fixed before making it look neat.

Additionally you cast the `const` away which is only 'safe' if you know that the pointed to memory will not be modified after all. If you do not need to modify your AT commands/repsonse, then they are effectively constant anyway and so you could simply use `const char*` for the relevant struct members throughout and use literals everywhere. By far the easiest solution, your code would look like this:

```
typedef struct {
  int     order;
  int     type;
  const char* cmd;
  const char* res[2];
  double  timeout;
  int     exitAfterNChar;
} atCmdList_t;

atCmdList_t atCmdList[] = {
  {0,0, "ATI", {"", ""}, 1, -1},
  {0,0, "AT+GSN", {"", ""}, 1, -1},
  {0,0, "AT+COPS?", {"+COPS: 0,0,\"vodafone IT\",2", ""}, 1, -1}
};
```

If you *do* need to modify them (then your C++ code may not have worked properly either), you need to do something involving:

1. `malloc()`/`calloc()` appropriate amount of memory first
2. `strncpy()` the `const char*` literall into the newly allocated memory of the struct member
3. when done, make sure to `free()` that memory again.

To give a toy example of how you could implement that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Foo 
{
  char * data;
};

char * copy_static_string(const char* src, size_t sz) 
{
  if(src) 
  {
    char * dst = malloc(sz);
    return dst ? strncpy(dst, src, sz) : NULL;
  }
  else 
  {
    return NULL;
  }
}

#define COPY_STATIC_STRING(x) (copy_static_string((x), sizeof(x)))

int main()
{
  struct Foo foo = { .data = COPY_STATIC_STRING("hello, world!") };
  printf("%s\n", foo.data); // check .data != NULL, don't forget!
  free(foo.data); // don't forget to clean up, either!
  return 0;
}
```

As an aside: the reason your C++ code 'works' is that `QString` is a container with copy-on-write semantics (detaching), so you can safely pass it `const char*` and QString will copy it when needed. (Therefore no attempt will be made to write to the original `const char*`).

Comment: Sorry, I've not checked, controlled or compiled the C code. :) My fault.
But thanks for the hint especially for pointing me to the error in the C ++ code.

Maybe I did not write the question properly, because my request is about searching the better and clearest way for write this type of C++ code in C, only for make it the most readable possible.

Comment: @user11804 I've given a toy example of the alternative.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
This is a good way but, my fault, I've not mentioned that I'm writing code for arm processor that have only a few kb of ram. 
This is a good alternative for system that have a large amount of ram, for example pc, or board that run linux.
In my case the use of malloc is not so good. The best is to have the string writed directly on the flash memory of the microprocessor and make some memcpy to a ram buffer only when needed. This is why I wanna use a preprocessor macro and not a function that put the string on ram at run time.